# Intersect differently typed Collections

Tags: java, collections, generic-collections

I have `Collection<A> ca` and `Collection<B> cb`, `A` and `B` sharing no common interface but each having a `String` property called `something`. I need to filter `ca` and retain only those elements which have a "corresponding" value in `cb`.

Unfortunately, creating a common interface for `A` and `B` as per [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845755/compare-and-sort-different-type-of-objects-using-java-collections) is not an option.

I'm currently doing

```
Iterator<A> it = ca.iterator();
while ( it.hasNext() ) {
    A a = it.next();
    if ( !cb.contains(new B(a.getSomething(), ... <known stuff>) )
        it.remove;
}
```

exploiting the fact that I know what `B.equals` does. Is there anything I can do to improve this, performance- and/or resource-wise?

Comment: It might help if people understood _why_ creating a common interface is not an option. E.g., do you not have access to change class A or class B?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, it's as simple as that. I cannot touch the code which gives me `as`. (WLOG :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you put the As and Bs into Maps, keyed by String? Then you could just use Collection.retainAll() a couple of times:

```
Map<String, A> as = new HashMap<String, A>;
for (A a: ca) as.put(a.getSomething(), a);
Map<String, B> bs = new HashMap<String, B>;
for (B b: cb) bs.put(b.getSomething(), b);
as.keySet().retainAll(bs.keySet());
ca.retainAll(as.values());
```

Bit mad, but there you go.

bs could be a `Set<String>` rather than a Map, but i like the symmetry.

Comment: This approach works just fine, particularly since it turned out that the corresponding `Map<A>`s were readily available from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Can you thought about creating new wrapper objects?

```
interface Holder {
    Object getThing(); //or a primative

class HolderA implements Holder {
    private A a;

    public HolderA(A _a) {
        a = _a;
    }

    public Object getThing() {
        return a.getSomething();
    }
}

class HolderB implements Holder {
    private B b;

    public HolderB(B _b) {
        b = _b;
    }

    public Object getThing() {
        return b.getSomething();
    }
}
```

I think you should be able to compare those two objects.

Comment: Yeah, that might be an option. Doubt if it'll really simplify in the end though... I'll look into it. +1

Comment: It feels less 'hackish' though, as this is instead using Object Oriented principles.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Guava Collections2](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html) class to `transform` and `filter` as follows:

```
Collection<A> as = ...;
Collection<B> bs = ...;

final Collection<String> b_somethings = 
    Collections2.transform(
        bs, 
        new Function<B, String>() {
            public String apply(B input) {
                return input.getSomething();
            }   
        });

Collection<A> filtered_as = 
    Collections2.filter(
        as, 
        new Predicate<A>() {
            public boolean apply(A input) {
                return b_somethings.contains(input.getSomething());
            }
        });
```